# Unix IPC socket: closing one end without reading from it

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, ipc, pipe

I have a parent process and a forked child process, and they share a Unix-domain IPC socket, created with `socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sockets)`. Both of the processes close one end of the socketpair, and save the other end into the `sock` variable. After that they do this:

```
int sock; // Unix-domain socket

void child_main()
{
  printf("I am child\n");      
  sleep(1);      
  close(sock);
}

void parent_main()
{
  printf("I am parent\n");

  write(sock, "hello", 5);

  char buf[100];
  int ret = read(sock, buf, 100); // this read will return ECONNRESET
  if (ret == -1) { 
    perror("read");
    exit(-1);
  }
}
```

Parent process writes some data into the socket, and the child *doesn't* read it. Instead the child closes the socket. Now my concern is that `read` in the parent process fails with ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer), while I would expect that it will return "0" indicating end of stream. Because the other end of the socket was *gracefully* closed by calling `close`.

Now, I understand that behaviour (closing the socket without reading pending data generates ECONNRESET), but where is this documented? [`man read`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) says nothing about ECONNRESET, but it mentions:

> Other errors may occur, depending on the object connected to fd

The [man page for unix domain sockets](http://linux.die.net/man/7/unix) only says:

> ECONNRESET: Remote socket was unexpectedly closed.

But since Unix-domain sockets are a local IPC thing, I suppose it could be much more specific about the circumstances when this error can happen.

My "deeper thoughts" are something like this: If the specification say e.g. `close` will generate end-of-stream mark only if there is no data to read from the socket, how does it know if the other process isn't just about to write some? Doesn't that create a race condition? How does the kernel know if the connection is going to be closed gracefully or not?

Comment: Not really sure if this will help, but have you tried using `shutdown()` prior to `close()`?

Comment: I just tried it and using `shutdown(); close();` behaves the same, but using `shutdown(); sleep(1); close();` actually closes the connection gracefully. So it seems it creates a race-condition, when the other-side of the socket "gets its turn" fast enough, it will be okay. So this is unwanted and I can't call `sleep(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

With stateful sockets (unix domain or tcp), the best way to distinguish "no data available"  and a close of the socket on the other end, is to first use select(), passing a readfds (see man 2 select). If, and only if the select indicates a read event, then try to read() on the socket. If the number of bytes read is 0, that means the socket was closed (connection reset by peer).